How to copy application between different versions of Ubuntu?
I have a multiboot system - Ubuntu 22 and Ubuntu 24.
I like to copy an application  from one to another.
I am asking for a solution.

Not recommended as you get into dependency hell. Versions are often different and need different dependencies. Part of advantage of snaps, but snaps can have their own issues. And some apps are not available in a newer version as considered not well supported and may have security issues. You do not mention what app which may make a difference.

Just use the command line/app store to manually install the app instead. You can only safely copy-paste an appimage. Otherwise, install manually.

FYI - AI posts are not allowed on this site.

Depends upon whether the application was packaged, and if so, how it was packaged. For example, an AppImage application can be easily copied. But a deb package application may require a bit more work. Snaps are in the middle. Tarballs you must read the instructions. It is a rich tapestry. Can you narrow the possibilities a bit?

You can't do it that way because the packages are different in different versions of Ubuntu, therefore a package that is installed in one version of Ubuntu is not likely to be compatible with a different version of Ubuntu. Just install it in the different version of Ubuntu using sudo apt install. The same type of command also works for installing multiple packages like this:
sudo apt install package1 package2 package3

No matter what the packaging format is (apt, snap, compiling from source code, etc.) it's always less error prone to install the package using the usual command used to install it in the terminal or from the App Center.
